# How to test repository with junit5 and testcontainers?

Tags: spring-boot, repository-pattern, junit5, testcontainers, testcontainers-junit5

I have a sample project in which I experiment with different technologies.

I have the following setup:

- Spring Boot 2.3.4.RELEASE
- Flyway 7.0.1
- Testcontainers 1.15.0-rc2
- Junit 5.7.0

How can I test the Repository layer with testcontainer-junit5?

Example of code I have now for `CompanyRepositoryTest.java`:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@Testcontainers
public class CompanyRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private CompanyRepository companyRepository;

    @Container
    public MySQLContainer mysqlContainer = new MySQLContainer()
            .withDatabaseName("foo")
            .withUsername("foo")
            .withPassword("secret");;

    
    @Test
    public void whenFindByIdExecuted_thenNullReturned()
            throws Exception {
        assertEquals(companyRepository.findById(1L), Optional.ofNullable(null));
    }

    @Test
    public void whenFindAllExecuted_thenEmptyListReturned() {
        assertEquals(companyRepository.findAll(), new ArrayList<>());
    }
}
```

When I add `@SpringBootTest`, I need to set up all the context and have some Application load context issues?

The question is, can anyone demystify what `@TestContainers` annotation does? What is the best practice or correct to use it while testing the Repository?

Comment: Apart from the already great answers, this guide also discuess all possible setup way for Testcontainers + Spring Boot + JUnit (4/5): https://rieckpil.de/howto-write-spring-boot-integration-tests-with-a-real-database/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [JUnit 5 extension](https://www.testcontainers.org/test_framework_integration/junit_5/) provided by the `@Testcontainers` annotation scans for any containers declared with the `@Container` annotation, and then starts and stops the those containers for your tests. Containers as static fields will be shared with all tests, and containers as instance fields will be started and stopped for every test.

If you are using Spring Boot, the easiest way to setup testcontainers for your tests is probably to provide properties in `application-test.yml`. This will use the datasource JDBC URL to launch the testcontainers container. Refer to Testcontainers [JDBC support](https://www.testcontainers.org/modules/databases/jdbc/) for more information.

You can also test just the repository layer by using `@DataJpaTest` instead of `@SpringBootTest`:

```java
@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
class CompanyRepositoryTest { }
```

Your `application-test.yml` file:

```yaml
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:tc:mysql:8.0://hostname/databasename
    driver-class-name: org.testcontainers.jdbc.ContainerDatabaseDriver
```

In some cases you might also want to use the `@TestPropertySource` annotation instead:

```java
@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
@TestPropertySource(
    properties = {
        "spring.datasource.url = jdbc:tc:mysql:8.0://hostname/test-database",
        "spring.datasource.driver-class-name = org.testcontainers.jdbc.ContainerDatabaseDriver"
    }
)
class CompanyRepositoryTest { }
```

Please note that the `hostname` and `test-database` are not actually used anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

You said

> When I add @SpringBootTest, I need to set up all the context and have
> some Application load context issues?

If you'd like to try an alternative and Testcontainer is not mandatory you can do it differently.

You do not need to load everyting when using SpringBootTest annotation, you can specify which classes are needed such as

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = { TheService.class })
```

or use `@Import` annotation

and mock others such as

```
@MockBean
MyService service;
```

For database connection you can use annotation such as

```
@ActiveProfiles("my-profile-for-jpa-test")
@DataJpaTest
@EnableJpaAuditing
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
```

EDIT: I feel like this should be an comment but I wanted to address the SpringBootTest part of the question with proper formatting

Comment: It is a nice answer, but I also want to use testcontainers. As it one of those technologies I want to assess. Also, I want specifically testcontainers + junit5, as I worked with testconatiners + junit4, and there are many references on the web of its usage, but not for junit5, yet.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example, how I configured Liquibase (a similar framework to Flyway) with MySql inside Spring:

```
@DataJpaTest
@TestPropertySource(properties = {"spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate"})
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
@ContextConfiguration(initializers = { MySqlLiquibaseBaseIT.Initializer.class })
@Testcontainers
public class MySqlLiquibaseBaseIT {

  @Container
  public static MySQLContainer<?> mysql = new MySQLContainer<>(
    DockerImageName
      .parse(MySQLContainer.NAME)
      .withTag("5.7.22"));

  @Configuration
  @EnableJpaRepositories
  @EntityScan
  static class Initializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {
    @Override
    public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext configurableApplicationContext) {
      TestPropertyValues.of(
        "spring.datasource.url=" + mysql.getJdbcUrl(),
        "spring.datasource.username=" + mysql.getUsername(),
        "spring.datasource.password=" + mysql.getPassword(),
        "spring.datasource.driver-class-name=" + mysql.getDriverClassName())
        .applyTo(configurableApplicationContext.getEnvironment());
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringLiquibase springLiquibase(DataSource dataSource) {
      SpringLiquibase liquibase = new SpringLiquibase();
      liquibase.setDropFirst(true);
      liquibase.setDataSource(dataSource);
      liquibase.setChangeLog("classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yml");
      return liquibase;
    }
  }
}
```

Full [MySqlLiquibaseBaseIT.java](https://github.com/AlexandrSokolov/datasource/blob/master/commons_test/src/test/java/com/savdev/datasource/MySqlLiquibaseBaseIT.java)

Answer (score 0):

1. As per [docs](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.testcontainers/junit-jupiter/latest/org/testcontainers/junit/jupiter/Testcontainers.html):

> The test containers extension finds all fields that are annotated with
> Container and calls their container lifecycle methods. Containers
> declared as static fields will be shared between test methods. They
> will be started only once before any test method is executed and
> stopped after the last test method has executed. Containers declared
> as instance fields will be started and stopped for every test method.

So in your case it will recreate a container for every test method, it's only responsible for starting and stopping the container. If you need some test data - that has to be done manually, as I see you have Flyway, that should do.

2. What "context issues" are you talking about?
3. Repositories are usually not tested separately, you can just test services which run repository methods instead of writing tests for both. If you want to test repos anyway - fill the database with some data in `@Before`.

If you have more questions please ask.

Comment: It's perfectly fine to integration test the repositories (or depending on your architecture, the persistence layer) separately. That's what the @DataJpaTest is for.